# When sending form with jQuery submit, $_POST is empty and $_REQUEST gets used instead

Tags: php, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
    $( ".product-form" ).submit();
});
```

Whenever I use a button outside of a form and use jQuery submit to submit the form instead, I end up getting an empty $_POST array and my $_REQUEST array gets filled instead? Is there a way to prevent this from happening and get the normal submit behavior?

```
<form class="product-form" action="<?=url("product/create", false, $query)?>">
...
</form>
```

Comment: you say $_POST is empty and $_REQUEST is filled. Have you checked the contents of $_GET? Perhaps the jquery submit is sending a GET request instead of a POST request?

Comment: Your form defaults to GET when no method is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is filled when your form method is `POST`. `$_GET` is filled when your form method is `$_GET`. `$_REQUEST` is filled in either case. If you're seeing your data in `$_REQUEST` but not `$_POST` then it means you're using `GET` in your form:

```
<form method="get" ...>
```

Change this to:

```
<form method="post" ...>
```

Comment: how do you change this?

Comment: ah, it worked, thanks.